# how to output the origin filename when the inputs are images in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg
' -vf select='gt(scene,0.4)' out_%d.jpg

In this command, i just want to select the separation frame from image sequences. But how can i make the output image filename same as the original image filename? Thx a lot.

for example:
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg

> > commmand

I want the result is:
2.jpg
instead of out_1.jpg